# Drupal ignores check_markup()

Tags: 6, input-formats

It seems like Drupal is ignoring `check_markup()`. What is wrong with the code below?

```
print check_markup($node->body, 'microblog', TRUE);
```

Site's default input format filter is = 'Filtered HTML'. All users have access to the 'microblog' filter, but I see my 'microblog' filter is kind of not working, and it uses filtered HTML.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Drupal 6, the second argument of `check_markup()` is the value of the "format" field in the "filter_formats" table; it is a serial field, which means it can contain only numbers.

The documentation for the function doesn't specify what you should pass; it uses a phrase that could be misunderstood, but it doesn't talk of format name.

> `$format` The format of the text to be filtered. Specify `FILTER_FORMAT_DEFAULT` for the default format.

Looking at how the function is called in [node_prepare()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_prepare/6), I noticed the code that calls the function is the following one:

```
  if ($teaser == FALSE) {
    $node->body = check_markup($node->body, $node->format, FALSE);
  }
```

The content of `$node->format` is always a number, in Drupal 6.

In a standard installation of Drupal 6, without any extra modules installed, these are the values for the format ID to pass to `check_markup()`:

```
Format ID     Input format
---------------------------
1             Filtered HTML
2             Full HTML
3             PHP code
```

To get the format ID knowing the name (e.g. "Filtered HTML"), you should use code similar to the following one:

```
$format_id = db_result(db_query("SELECT format FROM {filter_formats} WHERE name = '%s'", $format_name));
```

The format ID required from the function is different from a filter ID: An input format is a set of input filters that are used together to filter out or change what entered from users. What the modules implement are input filters.

Comment: Thank you very much. But why in API documentation it says that you could use the name of the filter as $format?

Comment: The documentation says, "The format of the text to be filtered." It doesn't say to use the name of the format, but it doesn't specify exactly what you should pass too.

Comment: Thanks for nice explaining this thing, really aprecciate that!